# Bad request for image path change using JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Here is the erb

`<%= image_tag('number-of-people/slide1.png', class: 'def-img-width nop-style1', alt: 'style1') %>`

Here is the JS

```
if(chooseframe == 1){
                $('.nop-style1').attr('src', "<%= image_path('number-of-people/style1-a3.png') %>");
            }else if(chooseframe ==2){
                $('.nop-style1').attr('src',  "<%= image_path('number-of-people/style1-a4.png') %>");
            }else if(chooseframe ==3){
                $('.nop-style1').attr('src', "<%= image_path('number-of-people/style1-a5.png') %>" );
            }
```

Here is the error message

Bad Request

bad URI `/order_details/%3C%=%20image_path('number-of-people/style1-a3.png')%20%%3E'.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.3/2015-08-18) at gates:3000

Here is the DOM element

```
<img class="def-img-width nop-style1" alt="style1" src="&lt;%= image_path('number-of-people/style1-a5.png') %&gt;" style="display: inline; -webkit-user-select: text;">
```

That means image_path is not getting executing!

Comment: Paste the complete code

Comment: I gave the details of exact problem. Because I am sure the function is getting executed and image_path is not working. What is your expectation?

Comment: which image_path is not working? JS code or ERB code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the code, but the thing is I had the above JS code in .js file. Which happens to use the erb syntax, for image_path . So I changed the file from **.js to .js.erb**